# Linux nuisance: /dev/stdin doesn't work with sockets

Tags: linux, shell-script, pipe, socket

Linux has this blitheringly annoying peculiarity that `/dev/stdin` won't work with sockets - it is hardcoded to return ENXIO. Try this:

```
socat TCP-OPEN:localhost:1234 EXEC:cat\ /dev/stdin,nofork
```

That's a perfectly reasonable command you'd expect to work, and does on basically every system, except Linux. (I'm using `cat` as a general example of any tool that opens a filename as the only way for you to specify a specific fd to use.)

The linux kernel is explicitly written to forbid sensible use of `/dev/stdin` in this way ­— see http://marc.info/?l=ast-users&m=120978595414993.

If you only need unidirectional capability, you can buffer the data in a separate process:

```
socat TCP-OPEN:localhost:1234 SYSTEM:'cat | thingy /dev/stdin'
```

It's wasteful, and worse, is useless if `thingy` is meant to be reading and writing to the same fd, because pipes are unidirectional in Linux.

What are we meant to do? `/dev/stdin` simply can't be used on Linux for building pipelines with bidirectional pipes, as far as I can tell, because sockets are the only underlying mechanism on Linux that yield a bidi stream with a single fd to read and write from (unlike a pair of pipes).

Comment: So what's the error, and which systems does that command work on? And, how does `cat /dev/stdin` usefully differ from `cat` in the first place, which doesn't try to re-open stdin?

Comment: I'm using cat as a general example of any tool that opens a filename, as a way for you to specify a specific fd to use. So it's not more useful than normal cat - but for lots of tools, passing a filename on the commandline is the only way to get them to use stdin. The error printed is "No such device or address", from open(2) returning ENXIO.

Comment: So this is specific to tools that don't take an argument like `-` to mean _use stdin for input_?

Comment: Yes - see the example in Linux's `proc(5)`. Overloading "-" is a bit nasty, and not every application does it. It's a complete pain that you can't open() /dev/stdin on linux when it's a socket, unlike every other system. I'll may have to hack in the "-" kludge to the application if there isn't a better way to do it.

Comment: I think it's either that or write a wrapper to forward stdin through a pipe or fifo - that's no better than your `cat|` solution though.

Comment: You mean you have a _thingy_ that takes a filename to open as argument and that expects to both read and write to it? That doesn't make much sense. Do you have an example of such an application?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's perfectly reasonable. Would there really be no security issue in allowing `open` to succeed and do essentially a `dup` when `/dev/fd/NUM` is a socket?

Comment: @Stephane A commercial unix application here that runs on Solaris/AIX and is launched with a load of inherited fds (Solaris bidi pipes, sockets), and what it does with each is given in some `/dev/fd/` arguments. It's looking like the linux version isn't going to be able to have the same scheme of arguments.

Comment: @Gilles Possibly - do you have an example of where it would be a problem? Solaris and others get away quite happily with open() working for sockets, so it can't be a big security issue. It would probably only affect poorly-written applications that make dodgy assumptions. We fstat fds passed in to see what type they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use an `LD_PRELOAD` trick to for Linux to mimic the BSD way. `fddup.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int whichfd(const char *pathname)
{
  unsigned int fd;
  if (sscanf(pathname, "/dev/fd/%u", &fd) == 1)
    return fd;
  else
    return -1;
}

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
  static int (*orig)(const char *, int, mode_t) = 0;
  int fd = whichfd(pathname);
  if (fd >= 0)
    return dup(fd);
  else {
    if (!orig)
      orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open");
    if (!orig) abort();
    return orig(pathname, flags, mode);
  }
}

FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
  static FILE *(*orig)(const char *, const char *) = 0;
  int fd = whichfd(path);
  if (fd >= 0)
    return fdopen(dup(fd), mode);
  else {
    if (!orig)
      orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen");
    if (!orig) abort();
    return orig(path, mode);
  }
}
```

(you may need to wrap more like `freopen()`).

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o fddup.so fddup.c -ldl
```

And then:

```
socat TCP:localhost:22 'EXEC:env LD_PRELOAD=./ddup.so cat /dev/fd/0,nofork'
```

Note that Linux and BSD are fundamentally different. It's not so much that you can't open `/dev/fd/0` when it's a socket, but that `/dev/fd/x` is a symlink to the file that is open on fd x. You can't do `open()` on a socket, that wouldn't make sense. `open("/dev/fd/x")` is not at all a `dup(x)` like in BSD. It feels like it when the file is a pipe, but it's not even then, it is in effect the same as as opening a named pipe (you can even open it in the other mode (read vs write) to get the other end of the pipe).

Both approaches have their pros and cons. It sounds to me your application should take fd numbers as arguments, not use `/dev/fd/x` which is a hack in the first place anyway and would for instance cause you to waste fds.